# Answer made a few days after a similar answer: is this plagiarism?

Tags: support, review-queues, late-answers

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39899901/bash-pod-command-not-found/41435900#41435900) appeared in my "First posts" queue (and for a moment it made me think I was in the "Late posts" queue, btw).

This answer does not add anything new to the question, as [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39899901/bash-pod-command-not-found/41245645#41245645) has already provided pretty much the same solution.

I certainly don't think this is an OK answer. But what exactly should I do?

1. Downvote and tell the user something in the lines of "thanks for participating, but your answer is identical to a previous one"?
2. Flag as plagiarism?

I chose option #1 but would like feedback from more experienced reviewers.

(**edit:** to contextualize the first two comments below, please view the edit history of this question)

Comment: The difference between answers is one minute. I'll choose third option • Move on.

Comment: Are you sure that was in the Late Answers queue? The question itself is no more than half an hour old, and the answer that supposedly appeared in your queue (by jrocha) *came first*.

Comment: I'm very sorry. I was thinking of the wrong queue. The difference between the answers is indeed very short and the appropriate action is indeed "move on".

Comment: (The reason for my confusion is that [this **arguably late** post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39899901/bash-pod-command-not-found/41435900#41435900) had just previously appeared to me in the "First post" queue; so when the second one appeared I thought I was in the "Late post" queue. Either way, time to stop reviewing for today.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While these two answer are *similar*, they are not *identical*. The commands in the answers **are** different. Furthermore, the newer answer includes two brief paragraphs with explanatory text that the older answer doesn't have.

Adding a new answer which includes details which are also in older answers is usually fine. I've often done this when I've felt that the existing answers don't contain enough details, don't adequately explain all the involved subtleties, contain errors which can't be fixed without significantly altering the content of the post, or are badly outdated.

This isn't plagiarism as I didn't *copy* anything from other authors. I merely used the same idea, which is something different.

Usually plagiarism is understood as wholesale copying of *non-trivial* text or code without attribution. What *doesn't* apply for this is basic commands or boilerplate code, as the amount of creative effort you need to put into that is trivial. If it would be considered plagiarism, then we'd have to mark a lot of `gem install`/`pip install`/etc. etc. answers are plagiarism :-)